# Matching Textgrid transcript to sound in Praat

Tags: phonetics, computational-linguistics, vowels, praat

I'm measuring the vowels in a whole boatload of recordings of the same item (e.g. 100 recordings of different people saying "my dog") in Praat. I am not very experienced in Praat, but figured out how to use this [vowel extraction script](http://lingtools.uoregon.edu/scripts/vowel_capture_aug09.praat) by Tyler Kendall. This script requires me to label the vowel in a Textgrid before measuring and I am now trying to be a bit more efficient. What I would like to do:

1. for each batch, create one Textgrid / text file with the relevant vowel transcription (e.g. *"o"*)
2. then read this Textgrid into Praat as my Textgrid with every single wav file of "dog" I open
3. and only adjust the size of the interval containing *o* according to its place in the actual recording (ie. drag it over the right interval, hit *Enter*)

Potentially:

4. save the Textgrid with the same name as the sound file or at least reset it to its original state (see below)

So 1-3 work well one time: For the first file, I can just adapt the length of the interval. However, for the next file, the interval from the first recording is now in the Textgrid file and whatever I do is just added to it.

Thus, what I write in 4.: Is there an easy way (faster than *Save as*) to save the Text-grid file, or to revert it to its initial state after measuring, or what would be the best approach?

I am working in Praat 5.3 on a Mac OS X.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Because TextGrids are just plain text files, you could generate all of these are separate files before even opening Praat. Then, step through them manually or with a Praat (editor) script. This depends on your abilities with manipulating batches of plain text files and Praat scripting.

Comment: @JeremyNeedle thanks, that's a good idea! ill see if i can get a script put together that matches sound file and and text-grid and opens them for me. that way, i can come back later and look at my alignments. thanks!